# Java : RegEx to find a substring Collection

Tags: java, regex, substring

I am using below java program to find list of js files as a Substring.

```
    String str = "jsLib//connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js , jsLib//connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents2.js;";
    String patternStr = "(\\/.*?\\.js)";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternStr);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(html);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println("Count:" + matcher.groupCount());
        jsLib = matcher.group(1);
        jsLib = jsLib.substring(jsLib.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, jsLib.length());
        System.out.println("jsLib:" + jsLib);
    }
```

**Regex** : I used `String patternStr="(\\/.*?\\.js)";`

**Expected Result** : both fbevents.js and fbevents2.js should be matched and part of result

**Actual Result** : only fbevents.js is matched

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may get all your results using `while` loop and a regex like `[^/]*\.js`:

```
String str = "jsLib//connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js , jsLib//connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents2.js;";
String patternStr = "[^/]*\\.js";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternStr);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("jsLib:" + matcher.group());
}
```

Output:

```
jsLib:fbevents.js
jsLib:fbevents2.js
```

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/jOFyMa) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zwbvAr/1).

The `[^/]*\.js` pattern matches any 0+ chars other than `/` (with `[^/]*`) and then a `.js` substring.